# Why do we use * while importing classes from packages in java?

Tags: java

For example while importing classes from IO package in java we use `import java.io.*`, instead of this why cant we use `import java.io` as import statement? When i use `import java.io` i get an error stating location: `package java`. Why is this error thrown?

Comment: The difference is that the first statement is valid in Java and the second one is not.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt You are not correct, why the second is invalid?

Comment: @RomanC No you are incorrect. I would expect someone with 15k rep to at least try to compile `import java.io;` before telling someone else they are incorrect.

Comment: I've mentioned in the question that when i compile with `import java.io` i get an error. :|

Comment: You only did that after I posted my comment... in the grace period so it doesn't show up in the logs. Anyhow, my comment is still valid - there's no use asking what the difference is between something that is valid and something that is not valid, because you can't use the thing that is not valid.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I didn't compiled it, because for such questions I don't use a compiler. But in my previous experience I frequently used to patch packages that I don't have access to. I thought `java` package is one of them. And if I use `io` as a custom class name, it should work. BTW I know that 15k is not 150k, and ppl easy gain it on java tag like below, swallow at 30 rep/day is SO pattern.

Comment: @Elysium You got error _error stating location: `package java`_. Means that at package `java` no class `io`. But it's a compiler eye, you should know that `io` is not a class, but a package name.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now. :)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt yes, I compiled it. Created package `java` and class `io` inside it, then use `import java.io;`. You said _No you are incorrect. I would expect someone with 15k rep to at least try to compile ..._ WTF? And what I will tell you: this effort cost to me 10 rep only, because it's SO.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can only import classes not package. `import java.io.*` will import all classes in `java.io` package

To import all the types contained in a particular package, use the import statement with the asterisk (`*`) wildcard character.

Now you can refer to any class or interface in the  package by its simple name.

Note: Another, less common form of import allows you to import the public nested classes of an enclosing class. For example, if the graphics.Rectangle class contained useful nested classes, such as Rectangle.DoubleWide and Rectangle.Square, you could import Rectangle and its nested classes by using the following two statements.

```
import graphics.Rectangle;
import graphics.Rectangle.*;
```

Be aware that the second import statement will not import Rectangle.

[see](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html) this page for more information on it

Comment: package would be a more appropriate term than directory :)

Comment: @Elysium, refer that link given in answer.  WhoAmI, it is changed..!!Thanks for head up..

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of the syntax. If you look how to import a specific class:

```
import java.util.List;
```

it seams consistent to express *import everything from some package* by using the asterisk `*` like in so many other environments: `pattern matching`, `Ant`, etc.

```
import java.util.*;
```

The asterisk has a history to match "everything".

And due to conventions and not any Java restrictions, you would not be able to distinguish between the sub-package `io` and a class named `io`. There is no compile error if you name a class not starting with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can import classes and packages. To import a class, you can use the fully qualified name of the class like

`import com.pkg.spkg.ClassName;`.

The package `spkg` may contain a lot of classes, and you require all of them in your application. In such a case the good idea would be to import all the classes or package itself. So to import the whole package we can use the wildcard `*` like

```
import com.pkg.spkg.*;
```

Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

`import java.io.*` will import all the classes from the io package. `io` is the name of the package and you need to import only classes.

You can alternatively import just the classes you need. Eg: `import java.io.BufferedInputStream`

Have a look at [java.io](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/package-summary.html) docs to find all the classes defined in the `java.io` package.

Also have a look at the [tutorial for packages](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html), to understand all about packages in java.

Answer (score 1):

Using * on

```
import java.io.*
```

Will import every classes in the io directory, you won't be able to import a directory.

Answer (score 1):

The second statement treated `io` as class, not package. That's why the error. You should read it carefully and use Java Naming conventions to properly name your classes.

The correct usage of import statement if you want to use `java.io` package classes

```
import java.io.*;
```

Answer (score 1):

`import java.io;` means import `class io` from package `java`. but the `io` class does not exist. java.io is a package, not a class.